# Azure DevOps Wiki: How to link inside a page?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-wiki

At my DevOps Wiki I have a page and want to create a index including links to the articles.
Mainly I find this manual to do this: [learn.microsoft.com...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#links)
But I don't get it working.

**How can I link inside a Wiki page? Could you show an example?**

I guess I have to set a anchor to the headers and link than the Index item to the anchor?!

Here a example:

```
Index
1.First article
2.Second article

#1.First article
bla bla bla ...

#2.Second article
bla bla bla ...
and a image
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you are suffering a bit of a nomenclature issue. Re: "*I have a **page** and want to create a **index** including links to the **articles**.*"

1. As a rule '*page*' and "*article*" are synonymous. As best I can tell, when you say "*article*" you mean sub-sections of the same page/article. Subsections of a page/article are delineated by you and your use of [headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#headers).
2. When you say "*index*", I imagine you mean the result provided by a [Table of contents (TOC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#table-of-contents-toc-for-wiki-pages). If you wanted greater control than the [TOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#table-of-contents-toc-for-wiki-pages) provides, you could construct your own "*index*" of links to just the headers of your choosing, e.g this sample page:

```
# My Index
1. [First Index Item, H1](#heading1).
1. [Second Index Item, H2.1](#heading2.1).
1. [Third Index Item, H4](#heading4).
1. [A heading with spaces](#heading-with-spaces)

# Heading1
Add a bunch of filler here to space out the page so you can see the result of selecting your '_Index_" items ([My Index](#my-index) above).

# Heading2
Add a bunch of filler here to space out the page.

## Heading2.1
Add a bunch of filler here to space out the page.

# Heading3
Add a bunch of filler here to space out the page.

# Heading4
Add a bunch of filler here to space out the page.

# Heading with Spaces
Add a bunch of filler here to space out the page.
```

Comment: Thank you.
I would like to add that it works fine with single words, but not when the linked Header has a space in between (e.g. '#My header'). Or I could not figure out how to use a header with space.

Comment: Right. I avoided spaces in my example for this reason. However, with Azure DevOps Wiki, you merely substitute a dash '-' for the space. For example, with your makrdown `#My header` the link to that is '#my-header`.

Comment: I should also note that I've found it best to use all lowercase in the link's text. Mixed case sometimes works fine but not always. Not sure why. Additionally, I've adopted the habit of ALWAYS including a space between the heading's final hash mark and its text, e.g. `# My headaer` instead of `#My header`. It doesn't seem to matter in Azure DevOps Wiki. However, other Wiki engines can be more finicky (and the [CommonMark specification](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#atx-headings) appears to call for this). It can be a headache if you port your content to another engine.

Comment: Notice too that you can retrieve the link to any heading. When viewing the page (not in edit mode) position your mouse on the same line as the heading whose link you want. An icon representing two chain links will appear just to the right of your heading. Click it and your browser's url will include the full link, ending in `?anchor=<your header link>`. Transform it to `#<your header link>` and you can use it in your Wiki pages to navigate to specific pages' header sections.

Comment: if you have a dot like `6. Header 6` you must escape the dot, so the result is `(#6\.-header-6)`

Comment: I think the solution below ([[_TOC_]]) works much better than creating an index by hand. It's faster to write, less maintenance-prone en has less code.

Comment: @PeterElzinga did you miss "...I imagine you mean the result provided by a [Table of contents (TOC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#table-of-contents-toc-for-wiki-pages)? Item #2.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to create a **Table of Content**
you don't have to do one by one; instead simply put the following code at the beginning of your ADO wiki article and you will automatically get what you are trying to do:

```
[[_TOC_]]

#1.First article
bla bla bla ...

#2.Second article
bla bla bla ...
and a image
```

Comment: Yep. Just like I said in my accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

here's an example for the syntax:

```
- [Article1](/Articles/Aricle1)
```

In the round brackets the path to the article relative to that wikipage is written.

Comment: This way I can link a page, but not a article or header inside the same page.